# Customising glossary group titles

Tags: glossaries, subdividing, naming

I'm using the `glossaries` package to produce multiple glossaries in the same document and have found it convenient to define my own glossary style.

When `makeindex` is used the glossary is sub-divided into a maximum of 28 logical blocks that are determined by the first character of the `sort` key set with `\newglossaryentry`. The sub-divisions are, respectively: *symbols*, *numbers*, and *A,...,Z*. I need to have three separate glossary groups, and for that I prepend the `sort` key of glossary entries with the following letters:

- **`a`** for a group of *numbers* and *letters*
- **`g`** for a group of Greek letters
- **`s`** for a group of subscripts

Here's a MWE (just run (pdf)latex twice on it with `--shell-escape`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomain,makeindex]{glossaries}

%% new glossary style
\newglossarystyle{onecol}{%
%
\renewenvironment{theglossary}%
{\begin{description}}{\end{description}}%
%
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
%
% indicate what to do at the start of each logical group
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{%
\item[{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}]}
%
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\indexspace}%
%
\renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
\item[\glstarget{##1}{##2}] ##3%
}%
}

%% glossary
\newglossary{model}{model.sys}{model.syo}{Nomenclature}

%% glossary entries
\newglossaryentry{L}{sort={aL},name={\ensuremath{\mathcal{L}}},type={model},
                       description={lift function}}
\newglossaryentry{CL}{sort={aCL},name={\ensuremath{C_L}},type={model},
                        description={lift coefficient}}
%
\newglossaryentry{alpha}{sort={galpha},name={\ensuremath{\alpha}},type={model},
                           description={angle of attack}}
\newglossaryentry{beta}{sort={gbeta},name={\ensuremath{\beta}},type={model},
                          description={sideslip angle}}
%
\newglossaryentry{fs}{sort={sfs},name={\ensuremath{\infty}},type={model},
                        description={free-stream condition}}

\immediate\write18{makeglossaries \jobname}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossary[type={model},style={onecol}]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The way `theglossary` environment is redefined above is somewhat redundant, but I only wish to provide a working example for now.

### Question

Is it possible to *remove* the title of the first group, and change the titles of the second and third groups to **Greek letters**, and **Subscripts**, respectively?

If yes, do I need to call `xindy` using my own style file or does a change in the way I define the glossary style `onecol` suffice?

Comment: I suspect the solution could be in `\glsgetgrouptitle` and/or `\...groupname`, but so far I've failed to find a workround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, but we can use the existing `\glsgetgrouptitle`. Note, however, that with this solution all your glossary entries should have an `a`, `g`, or `s` prefix in the sort key. Put

```
\newcommand*{\Agroupname}{}
\newcommand*{\Ggroupname}{Greek letters}
\newcommand*{\Sgroupname}{Subscripts}
```

into your preamble to obtain
[image: special nomenclature]

If desired, you may also redefine `\glsgroupheading` inside the `\newglossarystyle` declaration as follows (requires the `etoolbox` package):

```
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{%
\ifstrequal{A}{##1}{\relax}%
{\item[{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}]}%
}
%
\newcommand*{\Ggroupname}{Greek letters}
\newcommand*{\Sgroupname}{Subscripts}
```

This way `\glsgroupheading` does nothing at the start of the first glossary group:

[image]

Comment: I had tried to define the commands `\ggroupname`, and `\sgroupname`, but that didn't work. So in my ignorance I assumed `\Ggroupname` and `\Sgroupname` wouldn't work either. Can I please buy you a beer? :-)

Comment: @NunoNunes I read the source of `glossary.sty`. And YES! ;-)

Comment: Gentlemen, I have a problem now. I redefined \Agroupname etc., but now my headings in the ACTUAL glossary are redefined as well. Thus, headings above terms starting with an A are now for example in a section called "Greek Letters"... Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: @Ingo I'm afraid I can't follow. The question and the answer here deal with the case that you only have three groups, each with a single heading. You seem to want to have additional headings for alphanumeric sorting within these three main groups? Maybe you should ask a separate question for that.

Comment: Here's the deal. I have a list of acronyms, a list of symbols, a list of indices, and an actual glossary (of the style: Term - Description). I use the keys a-g for section in my lists, e.g. aA for classifying it as a Latin letter A. This I do by redefining `Agroupname` etc. What would happen then, however, is that in the actual glossary at the end of the document, there would not be a heading `A` anymore, but for example `Greek letters`. However, by now I have managed to work around this by Just redefining the commands at the end again...