# Glossaries: Supergroup for acronyms

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, makeindex

I use [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/188015/113610) to typeset my glossary, divided into three groups by parent and sub-entry. It works perfectly.
However, I would like to use this style for acronyms, in particular using `\setacronymstyle{long-short}`.
How can this be done?

Comment: You can use the optional argument of `\newacronym` to set additional keys, such as `parent`. For example, `\newacronym[parent=markup]{html}{HTML}{Hypertext Markup Language}`.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. I didn't know that's possible. Is there a list of the available keys one can use? (I couldn't find one in the manual)

Comment: All the keys that work with `\newglossaryentry` can be used in the optional argument of `\newacronym`. (`\newacronym` internally uses `\newglossaryentry` and just appends the optional argument to the end of the list.)

Comment: Good to know, thanks. One last comment: Would you mind posting your first comment as an answer, so I can flag the question solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the optional argument of \newacronym to set additional keys, such as parent. For example

```
\newacronym[parent=markup]{html}{HTML}{Hypertext Markup Language}
```

Any key that's available with `\newglossaryentry` is also available in the optional argument of `\newacronym`.