# group naming with altlist glossaries style

Tags: glossaries

I am working with the `altlist` style of the `glossaries` package and want to produce an output similar to the one [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/188015/48289) (i.e., using entries and subentries for manual grouping of the symbols). If I try the analogous code for `altlist`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[nopostdot,nonumberlist,acronyms,section]{glossaries}

\newglossarystyle{supergroup}{%
  \setglossarystyle{altlist}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \tabularnewline
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{%
     \bfseries\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}%
    }% 
    \tabularnewline
    \tabularnewline
  }%
  \renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{%
     \glssubentryitem{##2}%
     \glstarget{##2}{\glossentryname{##2}}
     &
     \glossentrydesc{##2}\glspostdescription\space
     ##3\tabularnewline
  }%
}

\newglossary[slg]{symbol}{sot}{stn}{Symbols}
\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{alpha}{
  type=symbol,
  name={Alphanumeric},
  description={}}

\newglossaryentry{greek}{
  type=symbol,
  name={Greek letters},
  description={}}

\newglossaryentry{area}{
  type=symbol,
  name={\ensuremath{S}},
  description={reference area},
  sort={S},
  parent=alpha
}
\newglossaryentry{span}{
  type=symbol,
  name={\ensuremath{b}},
  sort={b},
  description={wing span},
  parent=alpha
}
\newglossaryentry{dynp}{
  type=symbol,
  name={\ensuremath{q_\infty}},
  description={dynamic pressure},
  sort={q},
  parent=alpha
}
\newglossaryentry{aoa}{
  type=symbol,
  name={\ensuremath{\alpha}},
  description={angle of attack},
  sort={a},
  parent=greek
}
\newacronym
[sort={a}]
{bcr}{BCR}{Block Compressed Row}
\newacronym
[sort={a}]
{cad}{CAD}{Computer-Aided Design}

\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing

\section*{List of Symbols and Acronyms}
\glsaddall

\printnoidxglossary[type=symbol,style=supergroup]
\printnoidxglossary[type=acronym]

\end{document}
```

this gives some errors. How can I get this to work?

EDIT:

I have found a partial solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts, mathrsfs, amsmath, mathabx}
\usepackage[nopostdot,nonumberlist,acronyms,section]{glossaries}
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{sot}{stn}{Symbols}
\makenoidxglossaries
\newglossaryentry{alpha}{
  type=symbolslist,
  name={\hspace{4cm} Alphanumeric},
  description={},
  sort={A}
  }
\newglossaryentry{greek}{
  type=symbolslist,
  name={Greek letters},
  description={}
  }
\newglossaryentry{area}{
  type=symbolslist,
  name={\ensuremath{S}},
  description={reference area},
  sort={B}
  }
\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printnoidxglossary[type=symbolslist, style=altlist]
\end{document}
```

Now the entries with empty description field are boldface and can be shifted (as with the entry `alpha`) to the right. Is there any possibility to center those entries without manually using `\hspace{Xcm}`for appropriate `X`?

Comment: The problem is, `altlist` is a list-based style. You cannot use tabular stuff in a list. For that you must use a  `long` or `super` style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this more like it?

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[nopostdot,nonumberlist,acronyms,section]{glossaries}

\newglossarystyle{supergroup}{%
  \setglossarystyle{altlist}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \item[]%
     \makebox[\linewidth][c]{\bfseries\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}\glossentryname{##1}}
  }%
  \renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{%
    \item[\glssubentryitem{##2}%
      \glstarget{##2}{\glossentryname{##2}}]%
      \mbox{}\par\nobreak\glossentrydesc{##2}\glspostdescription\space ##3%
   }%
}

\newglossary[slg]{symbol}{sot}{stn}{Symbols}
\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{alpha}{
  type=symbol,
  name={Alphanumeric},
  description={}}

\newglossaryentry{greek}{
  type=symbol,
  name={Greek letters},
  description={}}

\newglossaryentry{area}{
  type=symbol,
  name={\ensuremath{S}},
  description={reference area},
  sort={S},
  parent=alpha
}
\newglossaryentry{span}{
  type=symbol,
  name={\ensuremath{b}},
  sort={b},
  description={wing span},
  parent=alpha
}
\newglossaryentry{dynp}{
  type=symbol,
  name={\ensuremath{q_\infty}},
  description={dynamic pressure},
  sort={q},
  parent=alpha
}
\newglossaryentry{aoa}{
  type=symbol,
  name={\ensuremath{\alpha}},
  description={angle of attack},
  sort={a},
  parent=greek
}
\newacronym
[sort={a}]
{bcr}{BCR}{Block Compressed Row}
\newacronym
[sort={a}]
{cad}{CAD}{Computer-Aided Design}

\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing

\section*{List of Symbols and Acronyms}
\glsaddall

\printnoidxglossary[type=symbol,style=supergroup]
\printnoidxglossary[type=acronym]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I linke the altlist style and with your solution the list of symbols looks completely different

Comment: How would you like it?

Comment: I just made an edit to my question with a partial solution. I still want the list of symbols have the altlist style but with manual "headers"

Comment: I have made my solution more like `altlist`. Please check if this is what you want. If not, please specify what should be changed.