# (glossaries) grouping symbols according to the sections under headings

Tags: glossaries

For `glossaries` package, I would like to group symbols according to the sections they first appeared in under the heading of the section name. Firstly, my code reads as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,blindtext,epsfig,epstopdf,titling,url,array,xspace}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2in,left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[nopostdot,style=super,toc]{glossaries}

\newglossary{symbols}{sym}{sbl}{List of Abbreviations and Symbols}
\newglossaryentry{aa}{type=symbols,name={aa},sort=aa,description={This is aa}}
\newglossaryentry{ab}{type=symbols,name={ab},sort=ab,description={This is ab}}
\newglossaryentry{ba}{type=symbols,name={ba},sort=ba,description={This is ba}}
\newglossaryentry{bb}{type=symbols,name={bb},sort=bb,description={This is bb}}
\newglossaryentry{ea}{type=symbols,name={ea},sort=ea,description={This is ea}}
\newglossaryentry{eb}{type=symbols,name={eb},sort=eb,description={This is eb}}
\newglossaryentry{fa}{type=symbols,name={fa},sort=fa,description={This is fa}}
\newglossaryentry{fb}{type=symbols,name={fb},sort=fb,description={This is fb}}
\makeglossary

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\printglossaries

\part{one}
\chapter{first}
\section{a}
\gls{aa},\gls{ab}
\gls{ea},\gls{eb}
\section{b}
\gls{ba},\gls{bb},\gls{aa}
\gls{fa},\gls{fb},\gls{ab}
\end{document}
```

The nomenclature prints as follows:
[image]

It seems the symbols are alphabetically grouped, but I would like to group them according to the sections they first appeared in under the heading of the section name (i.e. aa,ab,ea,eb are grouped under the title "a" and ba,bb,fa,fb are grouped under the title "b"). I spent so many hours trying to read the documentation but am struggling. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I only know `\usepackage[sort=use]{glossaries}`. So glossary will print the entries by order of appearance. But you also want to split the glossary into subglossaries(section wise)...

Comment: Do you mean: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89501/124842

Comment: What I mean is kind of similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188014/group-naming-with-super-glossaries-style?rq=1 but the headings are automatically generated according to the section names, I think I sort of found a way to deal with this. Thank you for your comment Bobyandbob, I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: If you find a solution, which works for you und can add a own answer (and accept). https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer .

Comment: Sure, I will wait a few more days to see if anyone could answer my question and if no one does then i will add my own best attempt.