# How to redefine the "Numbers" group in glossaries

Tags: glossaries, xindy

In this question:, [Customising glossary group titles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99142/customising-glossary-group-titles) , it have been instructed how to redefine group names of glossaries printed from the `glossaries` package using the function

```
\newcommand*{\Agroupname}{Roman letters}
\newcommand*{\Ggroupname}{Greek letters}
```

How to do the same thing for the "Numbers" group ?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
            xindy
            ]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}


%% glossary entries
\newglossaryentry{commut}{sort={0},name={\ensuremath{[~,~]}},
                       description={Commutator}}



\newglossaryentry{L}{sort={aL},name={\ensuremath{\mathcal{L}}},
                       description={lift function}}
\newglossaryentry{CL}{sort={aCL},name={\ensuremath{C_L}},
                        description={lift coefficient}}
%
\newglossaryentry{alpha}{sort={galpha},name={\ensuremath{\alpha}},
                           description={angle of attack}}
\newglossaryentry{beta}{sort={gbeta},name={\ensuremath{\beta}},
                          description={sideslip angle}}
%
\newglossaryentry{fs}{sort={sfs},name={\ensuremath{\infty}},
                        description={free-stream condition}}

\immediate\write18{makeglossaries \jobname}
\makeglossaries

% Define glossaries groups
\newcommand*{\Agroupname}{Roman letters}
\newcommand*{\Ggroupname}{Greek letters}
\newcommand*{\Sgroupname}{Subscripts}



\begin{document}
%\glsaddall
\printglossary[style=listhypergroup]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unsure if this is meant, but `glossaries` defines the macro `\glsnumbergroupname` which defaults to `Numbers`. Just redefine it!

(The macro is mentioned in the introduction section (page 32 of the current documentation, version 4.21, `glossaries` version from 2016/01/24)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
            xindy
            ]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}


%% glossary entries
\newglossaryentry{commut}{sort={0},name={\ensuremath{[~,~]}},
                       description={Commutator}}



\newglossaryentry{L}{sort={aL},name={\ensuremath{\mathcal{L}}},
                       description={lift function}}
\newglossaryentry{CL}{sort={aCL},name={\ensuremath{C_L}},
                        description={lift coefficient}}
%
\newglossaryentry{alpha}{sort={galpha},name={\ensuremath{\alpha}},
                           description={angle of attack}}
\newglossaryentry{beta}{sort={gbeta},name={\ensuremath{\beta}},
                          description={sideslip angle}}
%
\newglossaryentry{fs}{sort={sfs},name={\ensuremath{\infty}},
                        description={free-stream condition}}

\immediate\write18{makeglossaries \jobname}
\makeglossaries

% Define glossaries groups
\renewcommand{\glsnumbersgroupname}{Those are the numbers}
\newcommand*{\Agroupname}{Roman letters}
\newcommand*{\Ggroupname}{Greek letters}
\newcommand*{\Sgroupname}{Subscripts}



\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossary[style=listhypergroup]
\end{document}
```

[image]