# Change group names when using noidxglossaries

Tags: glossaries

With the `glossaries` package, the group names can be changed using the commands `\newcommand*{\Agroupname}{}`, `\newcommand*{\Bgroupname}{}`, etc,
as shown for example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290387/how-to-redefine-the-numbers-group-in-glossaries).

Here, I am obliged to use `\printnoidxglossary`, for which none of the previous commands seems to work, although `\renewcommand{\glssymbolsgroupname}{}` does work.

Any suggestion ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nogroupskip]{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{Almond}{ name=Almond,  description={A fruit},
  sort={Almond}  }
\newglossaryentry{Berry}{ name=Berry,  description={Another fruit},
  sort={Berry}  }
\newglossaryentry{Cherry}{ name={Cherry},  description={Yet another fruit},
  sort={Cherry}  }
\newglossaryentry{Tomato}{ name={Tomato},  description={Again another fruit},
  sort={Tomato}  }
\newglossaryentry{Strawberry}{ name={Strawberry},  description={Not a fruit},
  sort={Strawberry}  }


\makenoidxglossaries

\begin{document}
\gls{Almond}, \gls{Berry}, \gls{Cherry} and \gls{Tomato} are fruits, unlike \gls{Strawberry}.

%\renewcommand{\glssymbolsgroupname}{Non-fruits}
\newcommand*{\Agroupname}{a A}
\newcommand*{\Bgroupname}{b B}
\printnoidxglossary[sort=standard,style=listhypergroup]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have identified the issue, but I'm still working on a proper solution.

Internally, `glossaries` seems to store the titles as the unicode number so that 'A' is 65, 'B' is 66, etc.  The function which retrieves the title and check is the appropriate `\Xgroupname` command is set is (indenting mine):

```
\@gls@getgrouptitle=macro:
#1#2->\DTLifint {#1}{%
  \edef #2{\char #1\relax }%
}{%
  \ifcsundef {#1groupname}{%
    \def #2{#1}%
  }{%
    \letcs #2{#1groupname}%
  }%
}
```

From this command, it seems like `#2` is a char (A, B, ...) when using `xindy` or `makeindex`, but is an integer when using `noidx`.

The 'simple' thing to do is to redefine it so that it is an integer, it still checks if the appropriate `\Xgroupname` is defined.

The following is nearly what you want:

```
\def\@gls@getgrouptitle#1#2{
  \DTLifint {#1}{%
    \def\@tmp@char{\char#1}%
  }{%
    \def\@tmp@char{#1}%
  }%
  \ifcsundef {\@tmp@char groupname}{%
    \def #2{\@tmp@char}%
  }{%
    \letcs #2{\@tmp@char groupname}%
  }%
}
```

The only issue seems to be that `\def\@tmp@char{\char#1}` doesn't do what I want (comment on how to fix this would be appreciated).

### Update

After being unable to get `\def\@tmp@char{\char#1}` to do what I want, [I asked others](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/296211/26980).  The following uses Heiko's solutions:

```
\begingroup
  \catcode0=12 %
  \gdef\chrdef#1#2{%
    \begingroup%
      \lccode0=\numexpr(#2)\relax%
    \lowercase{\endgroup%
      \def#1{^^@}%
    }%
  }%
\endgroup

\def\@gls@getgrouptitle#1#2{%
  \DTLifint {#1}{%
    \chrdef\@tmp@char{#1}%
  }{%
    \def\@tmp@char{#1}%
  }%
  \ifcsundef {\@tmp@char groupname}{%
    \def #2{\@tmp@char}%
  }{%
    \letcs #2{\@tmp@char groupname}%
  }%
}
```

If you paste this in your preamble after loading the `glossaries` package (and inside `\makeatletter ... \makeatother`), then the glossary will use the names defined in `\Agroupmame`, `\Bgroupname`, ...

Here's a full MWE (which also includes the answer to [your other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/296202/26980))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  hmargin=8cm,
  showframe
]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[
  style=listhypergroup,
]{glossaries}
\renewcommand{\glossaryheader}{\item \parbox{0.9\textwidth}{\glsnavigation}}

\newglossaryentry{A}{name=A, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{B}{name=B, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{C}{name=C, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{D}{name=D, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{E}{name=E, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{F}{name=F, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{G}{name=G, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{H}{name=H, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{I}{name=I, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{J}{name=J, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{K}{name=K, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{L}{name=L, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{M}{name=M, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{N}{name=N, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{O}{name=O, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{P}{name=P, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{Q}{name=Q, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{R}{name=R, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{S}{name=S, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{T}{name=T, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{U}{name=U, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{V}{name=V, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{W}{name=W, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{X}{name=X, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{Y}{name=Y, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{Z}{name=Z, description={Letter of the alphabet}}

\makenoidxglossaries

\makeatletter
\begingroup%
  \catcode0=12 %
  \gdef\chrdef#1#2{%
    \begingroup%
      \lccode0=\numexpr(#2)\relax%
    \lowercase{\endgroup%
      \def#1{^^@}%
    }%
  }%
\endgroup

\def\@gls@getgrouptitle#1#2{%
  \DTLifint {#1}{%
    \chrdef\@tmp@char{#1}%
  }{%
    \def\@tmp@char{#1}%
  }%
  \ifcsundef {\@tmp@char groupname}{%
    \def #2{\@tmp@char}%
  }{%
    \letcs #2{\@tmp@char groupname}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\Agroupname{Alpha}
\newcommand\Bgroupname{Bravo}
\newcommand\Cgroupname{Charlie}

\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printnoidxglossary
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks a lot indeed. Although, in your example, there is a unwanted space before each letter. Is it possible to remove it ?

Comment: @HcN I have update the answer to fix the extra whitespace.  It was actually because I had forgotten a couple of `%` at the end of lines.