# List of letter not folding in glossaries

Tags: glossaries

In `glossaries`, using the option `listhypergroup`, there is a problem when the list of letters is too long and the page too narrow: as it does not fold, it goes over the page width to give

[image]

Is there a fix for this issue ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left = 8cm, right = 8cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nogroupskip]{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{Almond}{ name=Almond,  description={A fruit},
  sort={Almond}  }
\newglossaryentry{Berry}{ name=Berry,  description={Another fruit},
  sort={Berry}  }
\newglossaryentry{Cherry}{ name={Cherry},  description={Yet another fruit},
  sort={Cherry}  }
\newglossaryentry{Date}{ name={Date},  description={Yet another fruit},
  sort={Date}  }
\newglossaryentry{Elderberry}{ name={Elderberry},  description={Yet another fruit},
sort={Elderberry}  }
  \newglossaryentry{Flour}{ name={Flour},  description={Not a fruit but useful for cakes}, sort={Flour}}
\newglossaryentry{Grenade}{ name={Grenade},  description={Only the one that does not blow up is a fruit},  sort={Grenade}  }
\newglossaryentry{Hammer}{ name={Hammer},  description={Definitely not a fruit},  sort={Hammer}  }


\newglossaryentry{Tomato}{ name={Tomato},  description={Again another fruit},
  sort={Tomato}  }
\newglossaryentry{Strawberry}{ name={Strawberry},  description={Not a fruit},
  sort={Strawberry}  }
\newglossaryentry{Walnut}{ name={Walnut},  description={Shell fruit},
  sort={Walnut}  }


\makenoidxglossaries

\begin{document}
\gls{Almond}, \gls{Berry}, \gls{Cherry}, \gls{Elderberry}, \gls{Grenade}, \gls{Walnut} and \gls{Tomato} are fruits, unlike \gls{Strawberry}, \gls{Hammer} and \gls{Flour}.

%\renewcommand{\glssymbolsgroupname}{Non-fruits}
\printnoidxglossary[sort=standard,style=listhypergroup]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the navigation line is not breaking is that (for some reason) it is typeset within a `description` environment and the code is:

```
\item[<navigation line>]
```

I don't know why that is, but it turns out it can be easily fixed as the navigation line is set through the `\glossaryheader` command.  The only trick here is that since we are in a description environment, we want to avoid having the indentation that is associated with this environment, hence why I surround the navigation line in a `\parbox` in the solution below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  hmargin=8cm,
  showframe
]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[
  style=listhypergroup,
]{glossaries}
\renewcommand{\glossaryheader}{\item \parbox{0.9\textwidth}{\glsnavigation}}

\newglossaryentry{A}{name=A, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{B}{name=B, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{C}{name=C, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{D}{name=D, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{E}{name=E, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{F}{name=F, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{G}{name=G, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{H}{name=H, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{I}{name=I, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{J}{name=J, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{K}{name=K, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{L}{name=L, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{M}{name=M, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{N}{name=N, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{O}{name=O, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{P}{name=P, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{Q}{name=Q, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{R}{name=R, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{S}{name=S, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{T}{name=T, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{U}{name=U, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{V}{name=V, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{W}{name=W, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{X}{name=X, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{Y}{name=Y, description={Letter of the alphabet}}
\newglossaryentry{Z}{name=Z, description={Letter of the alphabet}}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Lastly, if you want to replace the `|` separator with something else, you have to redefine `\glshypernavsep`:

```
\renewcommand*{\glshypernavsep}{\space}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunalty, while this work in the MWE, it does not in my large document for a reason I failed to identify. In this document, I define other glossaries using `\altnewglossary{symbolsroman}{cnt}{Symbols (latin)}`, still using the `listhypergroup` style. Is it the same `\glossaryheader` function in this case ? If it is, I think I will stick to the `listgroup` style until I find out the reason for this.

Comment: @HcN This would be because `\glossaryheader` gets redefined whenever you change style.  Perhaps try redefining `\glossaryheader` *just* before your `\printglossary` command?

Comment: I get cryptic error messages (such as `Illegal parameter number in definition of \GetTitleStringResult.`) if I remove the `style=listhypergroup` option from `\printglossary`, even if I define it globally when loading the package. I do not understand what is going on, so I am obliged to keep it this way, and is certainly the reason why It does not work in my case.

Comment: Without being able to reproduce the error, it'll be hard for me to tell you what's going on.  Perhaps post another question with this new problem?  Curiously, are you also implementing my answer for [your other question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/296197/26980)?  Because it is possible that it only works this `listhypergroup` and not others (though I have not tested this).