# Expansion of \char in \def

Tags: tex-core, expansion, characters

In [answering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/296206/26980) [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/296197/26980), I ran into some issues trying to use a combination of `\def` and `\char`.  Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}
\makeatletter
\def\title@A{a A}
\def\title@B{b B}

\def\gettitle#1{
  \IfInteger{#1}{%
    \def\@tmp{\char#1}%
    \ifcsundef{title@\@tmp}{\@tmp}{\csname title@\@tmp\endcsname}%
  }{%
    \ifcsundef{title@#1}{#1}{\csname title@#1\endcsname}%
  }
}
\begin{document}
\gettitle{65}  \gettitle{A}

\gettitle{66}  \gettitle{B}

\gettitle{67}  \gettitle{C}
\end{document}
```

Output:

> A  a A
>
> B  b B
>
> C  C

It seems like `\@tmp` does not expand to be a single character, but instead expand to `\char 65`, which then doesn't work in `\csname ... \endcsname`.  I thought that using `\edef\@tmp{\char#1}` would work, but it seems like `\char` is one of those functions that does not get expanded.

So in the end, is it possible to have `\@tmp` expand to `A` and *not* `\char 65`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be done via the  `\lowercase` trick:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}
\makeatletter

\begingroup
  \catcode0=12 %
  \gdef\chrdef#1#2{%
    \begingroup
      \lccode0=\numexpr(#2)\relax
    \lowercase{\endgroup
      \def#1{^^@}%
    }%
  }%
\endgroup

\def\title@A{a A}
\def\title@B{b B}

\def\gettitle#1{
  \IfInteger{#1}{%
    \chrdef\@tmp{#1}%
    \ifcsundef{title@\@tmp}{\@tmp}{\csname title@\@tmp\endcsname}%
  }{%
    \ifcsundef{title@#1}{#1}{\csname title@#1\endcsname}%
  }
}
\begin{document}
\gettitle{65}  \gettitle{A}

\gettitle{66}  \gettitle{B}

\gettitle{67}  \gettitle{C}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

`\lowercase` (a not expandable command) converts the argument character token to its lower case character. This is configured by `\lccode`. The only exception is zero. If the `\lccode` is zero for a character, then the character remains unchanged. Therefore the example uses the character with code zero, which can be expressed as `^^@` in TeX notation. However, this character has usually the category code of invalid, there it is changed to 12 (other) in the outside group. Since the changes to `\lccode` should be reverted afterwards, the macro also uses a group.

Comment: Could you please give an explanation (or link to explanation) of what this `\lowercase` trick does?

Comment: @JP-Ellis http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156759/the-lowercase-trick

Answer (score 9):

The `\char` primitive isn't expandable. In XeTeX and LuaTeX we have `\Uchar`, which is and so can generate any character. For pdfTeX, with only 256 possible outcomes, we can set up a look-up table. Something like

```
\catcode`\@=11 %
\ifdefined\Uchar
  \def\Xchar#1{%
    \detokenize\expandafter{\Uchar\numexpr #1\relax}%
  }
\else
  \catcode`\^^@=12 %
  \begingroup
    \gdef\Xchar#1{%
     \romannumeral-`\0\expandafter\Xchar@aux\expandafter{\numexpr #1\relax}%
    }
    \gdef\Xchar@aux#1{%
      \ifcsname Xchar@\romannumeral #1\endcsname
        \csname Xchar@\romannumeral #1\endcsname
      \else
        \errmessage{Character out of range}%
      \fi
    }
    \count@=-1 %
    \lccode`\X=`\X %
    \loop
      \advance\count@ by 1 %
      \ifnum\count@<256 %
      \lccode`\^^@ = \count@ %
      \lowercase{%
        \expandafter\gdef\csname Xchar@\romannumeral\count@\endcsname{^^@}%
      }
    \repeat
  \endgroup
\fi
\catcode`\@=12 %
```

provide `\Xchar` to do the job. A more sophisticated version of the same idea can be used to provide different category code characters, and is implemented as `\char_generate:nn` in `expl3`. (The above is expandable at point-of-use as the lookup table is generated in advance.)

Comment: I'll have to analyse this answer some more to understand it... but since you mention `\char_generate:nn`, does that mean that there is a nice(r) LaTeX3 way of doing expanding `\def\@tmp{\char#1}`?