# Adding hyperref/links on each entry of list of symbols

Tags: hyperref, glossaries

I want to add links after each symbol in my list of symbols and also during usage in the text. I did not include option `nonumberlist` when loading `glossaries` package, and still, the links don't appear. The grouping of different types of symbols is based on the method mentioned in [Customising glossary group titles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99142/customising-glossary-group-titles)

Here is my mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopostdot,nomain,makeindex,acronym, toc, ucmark]{glossaries}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
%% new glossary style
\newglossarystyle{onecol}{%
%
\renewenvironment{theglossary}%
{\begin{description}}{\end{description}}%
%
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
%
% indicate what to do at the start of each logical group
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{%
\item[{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}]}
%
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\indexspace}%
%
\renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
\item[\glstarget{##1}{##2}] ##3%
}%
}

%% glossary
\newglossary{model}{model.sys}{model.syo}{List of Symbols}

%% glossary entries
\newglossaryentry{alpha}{sort={galpha},name={\ensuremath{\alpha}},type={model},
                           description={Angle1}}
\newglossaryentry{beta}{sort={gbeta},name={\ensuremath{\beta}},type={model},
                          description={Angle2}}
%
\newglossaryentry{r}{sort={rr},name={$R$},type={model},
                        description={System response}}
\immediate\write18{makeglossaries \jobname}
\newcommand*{\Ggroupname}{Greek Letters}
\newcommand*{\Rgroupname}{Roman Letters}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\glsaddall[types={model}]
\printglossary[type={model},style={onecol}]
\pagebreak{}
Usage of \gls{alpha}.

Usage of \gls{beta}.

Usage of \gls{r}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You've omitted the location list (`##5`) in the new definition of `\glossaryentryfield`, which is why it doesn't appear. (Note that `\glossaryentryfield` is now deprecated.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

I included your suggestion and now not only appears the page number where the symbol is used in the text but also the page number of the "List of symbols" page.

How can I exclude the page number of the "List of symbols" page?

Comment: You can use `nonumberlist` in the option argument of `\printglossary`, for example, `\printglossary[nonumberlist,type=symbols]`.

Comment: `\printglossary[nonumberlist,type=symbols]` that does not suit my intentions because the page number related to the first symbol's occurrence in  the text is also deleted, which is the only one I want.